# Cannot execute runserver in Django: "TypeError: putenv() argument 2 must be string, not None"

Tags: django, linux

I made and successfully ran Django project in Windows, but after copying it to Linux and executing command "python manage.py runserver" following error occured:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE")
  File "/home/blizzard/webapps/django_1_3/moz455/env0/lib/python2.6/UserDict.py", line 63, in setdefault
    self[key] = failobj
  File "/home/blizzard/webapps/django_1_3/moz455/env0/lib/python2.6/os.py", line 472, in __setitem__
    putenv(key, item)
TypeError: putenv() argument 2 must be string, not None
```

Right values for key and item are "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE" and "settings".
How to avoid this error?

Comment: You could create a project w/ same name and copy the `manage.py` from it. Or simply try to fix by    `os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", 'settings')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is so simple that this question should not be asked :) But maybe it save somebody several minutes.
For Linux correct command is

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", 'my_project_name.settings')
```